# How to remove icon(name) of an uninstalled application in elementary OS?

Tags: applications

I have installed `xdman` using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xdman
```

I removed with the command:

```
sudo apt-get purge xdman
```

But name still appear in menu, like

[image: Xdman Blank Icon]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**General solution**:

Let `app_name` is name of the application.

Open terminal and run

```
grep app_name ~/.local/share/applications/*
```

If there is `.desktop` file, run:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/applications/app_name.desktop
```

This should solve the problem.

Read [man grep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) and [man rm](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_rm.htm) for commands explanation.

*Optional*:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/app_name.desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

**For this particular case**: See [chat discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32464/ravan-and-ferry)

In this case, the `app_name` is xdman but the `.desktop` is `xdm.desktop`. So run:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/applications/xdm.desktop
```

This worked for me, but not to OP.

So, we enabled PPA, then reinstalled. Now again, removed with simple command:

```
sudo apt-get purge xdman
```

Answer (score 0):

First try,

> sudo apt autoremove

This should clean up any dependent packages that would result in this behavior.

Maybe the OS should perform this regularly or the uninstall process should also consider removing "unused" packages after removing an App.

Deleting of the *.application files should come as the next, or maybe optional step, as it will fix the symptom and not the cause.

Regards,
K